# How to write a variable in a file with a new line every time (answers seen dont work)

Tags: python

I want to write a variable into a file with a new line every time. All fixes i have seen dont work. I know to use '\n' and add it to the variable but it isnt actually doing anything.

```
file.write(searchString + '\n')

file.write(searchString)
file.write('\n')

file.write('searchString \n')
```

These above is what i ahve attempted in terms of adding a new line
below is my actaul code which i need to implement the new line fix into

```
import csv

searchString = input("Please enter a string to be searched through: ")

fileList = ["prices.csv", "pricessplit.csv", "securities.csv", "fundamentals.csv"]

file = open(searchString+ ".txt", "a", newline="")
file.write(searchString + '\n')


index = 0
fileType = []
for i in fileList:
    with open(fileList[index], "r") as b:
        file.write(fileList[index] + '\n')
        reader = csv.reader(b, delimiter=",",)
        for row in reader:
            for field in row:
                 if field == searchString:
                     print(row)
                     file.write(str(row))
                     file.write("\n")
    index = index + 1
```

I want it to be in a text file with a new line after every data entry
Im using stovks so i want it to show searchString - new line
then prices.csv
then show all the stocks but having a new line after all data from each row has been written

The expected output should be:

```
OKE

prices.csv
['2010-01-04', 'OKE', '44.880002', '45.579999', '44.880002', '45.709999', '1759600.0']
['2010-01-05', 'OKE', '45.500002', '45.18', '44.589999', '45.749998', '3324900.0']
['2010-01-06', 'OKE', '45.270001', '45.44', '45.000002', '45.530001', '1769400.0']
['2010-01-07', 'OKE', '45.510002', '45.140001', '44.839999', '45.510002', '1609800.0']
['2010-01-08', 'OKE', '45.109998', '45.400001', '44.770001', '45.449999', '1061300.0']
['2010-01-11', 'OKE', '45.68', '46.410001', '45.44', '46.510002', '1793000.0']
['2010-01-12', 'OKE', '46.209999', '45.729998', '45.56', '46.369998', '1631200.0']
['2010-01-13', 'OKE', '45.989998', '45.92', '45.55', '45.989998', '876900.0']
```

but what i am getting is:

```
OKEprices.csv['2010-01-04', 'OKE', '44.880002', '45.579999', '44.880002', '45.709999', '1759600.0']
['2010-01-05', 'OKE', '45.500002', '45.18', '44.589999', '45.749998', '3324900.0']
['2010-01-06', 'OKE', '45.270001', '45.44', '45.000002', '45.530001', '1769400.0']
['2010-01-07', 'OKE', '45.510002', '45.140001', '44.839999', '45.510002', '1609800.0']
['2010-01-08', 'OKE', '45.109998', '45.400001', '44.770001', '45.449999', '1061300.0']
```

Comment: any help very much appreciated :)

Comment: You are using `file` before assigning it.

Comment: @KlausD. im not sure why it has done that my code starts from import csv. Thanks for the help wondering if you have any other ideas - much appreciated

Comment: Those are what i have attempted - the stuff above import csv

Comment: You should make that clear in your question and add a proper description of the problem. What is the expected and observed output?

Comment: @KlausD.i have now updated and shown expected and current outputs Could you possibly help me now?

Comment: @KlausD. thanks for editing my code can you show me now how to write a variable on a new line in a file please

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine when I tried it with my own .csv file.
Did you check your file separately? Or can you give a link so that I can check with that.

Comment: Your problem seems to appear before ever touching the CSV file (no line break between `OKE` and `prices.csv`. Please turn this into a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).